# Ubuntu 13.10 Sound not working after modifying fstab

Tags: partitioning, sound, mount, ntfs, fstab

I want to auto mount a ntfs partition after system start. Therefore i edited /etc/fstab and added this new entry:

```
UUID=someuuid    /home/someusername    ntfs    defaults    0    2
```

Mounting works but i have no sound anymore and the volume symbol in unity or gnome vanished.
Anyway if i mount the partition to /media/somename mounting and sound works.

The partition contains the folders 'Downloads' and 'Dropbox' and 'Pictures' aswell as one file. I made sure my home folder does not contain those folders or files.

I got the same Problem if i move the home folder to another partition the same way as described on this website:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

What is the matter here and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly [the same problem](https://askubuntu.com/users/243241/erres?tab=questions) with mounting /home on another partition and having no sound. Formatting the partition to ext4 and mount /home again solved it for me.